# Material-ui adding Link component from react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I'm struggling to add `<Link/>` component to my material-ui AppBar

This is my navigation class:

```
class Navigation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    var styles = {
      appBar: {
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
      },
      tabs: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }

    return (
      <AppBar showMenuIconButton={false} style={styles.appBar}>
        <Tabs style={styles.tabs}>
          <Tab label='Most popular ideas'/>
          <Tab label='Latest ideas' />
          <Tab label='My ideas' />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
    )
  }
}
```

Which looks okay:
[image: Navbar]

Tabs are clickable, have fluid animations, that's cool. But how do I wire them up together with `react-router` and its' `<Link/>` component?

I've tried adding `onChange` listener like that:

```
<Tab
  label='My ideas'
  onChange={<Link to='/myPath'></Link>}
/>
```

However I'm getting following error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Expected onChange listener to be a function, instead got type object
```

If I try to wrap `<Tab/>` component into `<Link/>` component, I'm getting error that `<Tabs/>` component accepts only `<Tab/>` component.

This doesn't work either (no error is being produced, but clicking on Tab does not bring me to the path):

```
<Tab label='Most popular ideas'>
  <Link to='/popular'/>
</Tab>
```

How do I make `<Link/>` component work together with `<Tabs>` and `<AppBar>`? If that's not possible, I can use any other component from `material-ui` library to form a proper menu.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

For Material UI 1.0 with Typescript: see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46686467/2790937) by @ogglas below.

For Material-UI 1.0 with plain JS:

```
<Tabs value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
  {
    this.props.tabs.map(
      ({label, path})=><Tab key={label} 
                            label={label} 
                            className={classes.tabLink} 
                            component={Link} 
                            to={path} />
    )
  }
</Tabs>
```

And `classes.tabLink` is defined as:

```
tabLink : {
    display:"flex",
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent:"center"
}
```

### How this works?

All the mui 1.0 components inheriting from `ButtonBase`, support a `component` prop, see [ButtonBase](https://material-ui-next.com/api/button-base/). The idea is to allow you to control what the component renders as its wrapper/root element. `Tab` also has this feature although at the time of writing this answer this prop is not documented *explicitly*, but as `Tab` inherits from `ButtonBase`, all its props carry over (and the documentation does cover this).

Another feature of `ButtonBase` is that all the extra props, not in use by `ButtonBase` or inherited component, are spread over the specified `component`. We have used this behavior to send the `to` prop used by `Link` by giving it to `Tab` control. You can send any additional props in the same way. Note that this is documented explicitly for both `ButtonBase` and `Tab`.

Thanks @josh-l for asking this to be added.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what the arguments being passed in for the "component" and "to" apis are? I was looking at the material UI v1 api tab documentation and it's not showing either of these? https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/api/tab/

Comment: For most of the mui container components, you can send a `component` prop to make it use a different React component instead of the default one. In this example, we are making Tab render the react router Link control. In this mode, the mui component will pass any extra props to that component. As Link requires a `to` prop, I am passing that in Tab. You will find this behavior documented somewhere in mui. Will try to update my answer soon.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Got it working! But yeah perhaps updating the answer with a bit more detail could help others. Upvoted it either way!

Answer (score 33):

here's how you can do it now:

```
<Tabs onChange={this.changeTab} value={value}>
   <Tab value={0} label="first" containerElement={<Link to="/first"/>} />
   <Tab value={1} label="second" containerElement={<Link to="/second"/>}/>
   <Tab value={2} label="third" containerElement={<Link to="/third"/>} />
 </Tabs>
```

Comment: Sweet. But I noticed that the docs don't say this. Do all elements support `containerElement`?

Comment: the ones I tried (that made sense for them to have it) they did have it

Comment: At time of writing this technique doesn't appear to work on `material-ui@next`.

Answer (score 26):

You can try this simple method

```
 <Tab label='Most popular ideas'  to='/myPath' component={Link} />
```

Comment: This worked for me. However, is there anyway to remove the 'blue underline' link styling?

Comment: This should be the correct answer now with latest material-ui 4+

Comment: Still a simpler solution in 2020

Comment: throws `Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.` for me

Comment: No error is thrown but it is not working for me. running 4.11 core ui

Comment: Thank you, this is working great and should be the correct answer.

Comment: I am not able to get it to working. There addListner issue TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')

Answer (score 13):

This is solved using the `<Link />` from material-ui instead of directly using the `<Link />` or `<NavLink />` from react-router. The example for the same can be found in the documentation here.

https://material-ui.com/components/links/

Also `<Button />` tag has a component prop to achieve this

```
<Button color="inherit" component={Link} to={"/logout"}>Logout</Button>
```

An extensive discussion on this can be found here

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/850

Answer (score 8):

Since we are using TypeScript I could not use @hazardous solutions. This is how we implemented routing for `material-ui v1.0.0-beta.16` and `react-router 4.2.0`. The reason why we are splitting `this.props.history.location.pathname` is because we need to access `/renewals/123` for example. If we did not do this we would get the following warning and no tab would be displayed as active: `Warning: Material-UI: the value provided '/renewals/123' is invalid`

Complete code with imports:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as ReactRouter from "react-router";
import * as PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, Link  } from "react-router-dom";
import { Cases } from './../Cases';
import { SidePane } from './../SidePane';
import { withStyles, WithStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import Tabs, { Tab } from 'material-ui/Tabs';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Badge from 'material-ui/Badge';
import Grid from 'material-ui/Grid';
import { Theme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import SimpleLineIcons from '../../Shared/SimpleLineIcons'

interface IState {
    userName: string;
}

interface IProps {
    history?: any
}

const styles = (theme: Theme) => ({
    root: theme.typography.display1,
    badge: {
        right: '-28px',
        color: theme.palette.common.white,
    },
    imageStyle:{
        float: 'left',
        height: '40px',
        paddingTop: '10px'
    },
    myAccount: {
        float: 'right'
    },
    topMenuAccount: {
        marginLeft: '0.5em',
        cursor: 'pointer'
    }
});

type WithStyleProps = 'root' | 'badge' | 'imageStyle' | 'myAccount' | 'topMenuAccount';

class Menu extends React.Component<IProps & WithStyles<WithStyleProps>, IState> {
    constructor(props: IProps & WithStyles<WithStyleProps>) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userName: localStorage.userName ? 'userName ' + localStorage.userName : ""
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ userName: localStorage.userName ? localStorage.userName : "" })
    }
    logout(event: any) {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        window.location.href = "/"
    }

    handleChange = (event: any, value: any) => {
        this.props.history.push(value);
    };

    render() {
        const classes = this.props.classes;
        let route = '/' + this.props.history.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
        return (
            <div>
                <Grid container spacing={24}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.root}>
                        <img src="/Features/Client/Menu/logo.png" alt="Logo" className={classes.imageStyle} />
                        <div className={this.props.classes.myAccount}>
                        <span><span className={this.props.classes.topMenuAccount}>MY ACCOUNT</span><span className={classes.topMenuAccount}><SimpleLineIcons iconName={'user'} />&#x25BE;</span></span>
                            <span onClick={this.logout} className={classes.topMenuAccount}><SimpleLineIcons iconName={'logout'} /></span>
                        </div>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} >
                        <div className="route-list">
                            <Tabs
                                value={route}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                indicatorColor="primary"
                                textColor="primary"
                            >
                                <Tab label="Overview" value="/" />
                                <Tab label={<Badge classes={{ badge: classes.badge }} badgeContent={this.props.caseRenewalCount} color="primary">
                                    Renewals
                                   </Badge>} value="/renewals" />
                            </Tabs>
                        </div>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default withStyles(styles)(withRouter(Menu))
```

Answer (score 5):

## TypeScript implementation of the router-driven tabs.

For those who look for the TypeScript implementation. Easy configurable. Driven by `tabs` configuration.

```
interface ITabsPageProps {
  match: match<{page: string}>;
  history: History;
}

const tabs = [{
  label: 'Fist Tab',
  link: 'fist-tab',
  component: <FirstTabContent/>
}, {
  label: 'Second Tab',
  link: 'second-tab',
  component: <SecondTabContent/>
}, {
  label: 'Third Tab',
  link: 'third-tab',
  component: <ThirdTabContent/>
}];

export class TabsPage extends React.Component<ITabsPageProps> {
  handleChange(tabLink: string) {
    this.props.history.push(`/tabs-page/${tabLink}`);
  }

  render() {
    const currentTab = this.props.match.params.page;
    const selectedTab = tabs.find(tab => currentTab === tab.link);

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Tabs
          value={currentTab}
          onChange={(event, value) => this.handleChange(value)}
        >
          {tabs.map(tab => (
            <Tab
              key={tab.link}
              value={tab.link}
              label={tab.label}
            />
          ))}
        </Tabs>

        {selectedTab && selectedTab.component}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another implementation of React with hooks, Material-UI with tabs, React Router with Link, and TypeScript.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch, Link, LinkProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import { default as Tab, TabProps } from '@material-ui/core/Tab';

import Home from './Home';
import ProductManagement from './ProductManagement';
import Development from './Development';
import HomeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Home';
import CodeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Code';
import TimelineIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Timeline';

const LinkTab: React.ComponentType<TabProps & LinkProps> = Tab as React.ComponentType<TabProps & LinkProps>;

function NavBar() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: number) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <div >
      <AppBar position="static" >
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} centered>
          <LinkTab label='Home' icon={ <HomeIcon />} component={Link} to="/" />
          <LinkTab label='Development' icon={<CodeIcon />} component={Link} to="/dev" />
          <LinkTab label='Product Management' icon={<TimelineIcon />} component={Link} to="/pm" />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  )
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={ Home } />
          <Route exact path="/dev" component={ Development } />
          <Route exact path="/pm" component={ ProductManagement } />
          <Redirect from="/" to="/" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Comment: Looks fine. There is one problem - how to set initial state of tabs? You use "0", so it's path to "/home", but what if user will start with "/dev" path?

Answer (score 4):

If you use NextJs, you can do it like that, and create your own component.

*i didn`t wrap the Tab with 'a' tag, because it added automatically

```
const WrapTab = (props) => {
const { href } = props
return (
<Link href={href} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
  <Tab {...props} />
</Link>
)}
```

and then this is your return

```
    <Tabs
      value={value}
      indicatorColor="primary"
      textColor="primary"
      onChange={handleChange}
      variant="fullWidth"
    >
        <WrapTab href="/testPage/?tab=0" icon={<MenuIcon />} />
        <WrapTab href="/testPage/?tab=1" icon={<StampIcon2 />} />
        <WrapTab href="/testPage/?tab=2" icon={<ShopIcon />} />
        <WrapTab href="/testPage/?tab=3" icon={<PenIcon />} />
        <WrapTab href="/testPage/?tab=4" icon={<ProfileIcon />} />
    </Tabs>
```

link to material-ui docs:
https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/

Answer (score 3):

So my work-around for this solution has been quite reliable, though it may be more manual of a solution than what you're looking to do.

The strategy that I've been using is to actually not even use the Link Component. Instead, you'll utilize the Tabs onChange property as a callback that can respond to Tab clicks, and track location manually with Props on the Parent.

You can import a utility called History from react-router that will allow you to manually push locations. While using React-Router, your component tree will have access to Location prop that has a pathname key with the string of your current location.

We will manually parse this string into the components that make up your current URL, then use a Switch statement to decide both which tab is currently selected and also where to link to when a tab is clicked. (This gives you a fair amount of control over navigation)

( e.g. ['', 'latest'] )

Here is a mock up of what your component MAY look like after integrating this solution.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {History} from 'react-router';

function parseLocation(location) {
    if (String(location)) {
        var locationArray = location.split('/');
        return locationArray;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
function filterPath(path) {
    let locationArray = parseLocation(path);
    return locationArray[locationArray.length - 1];
};
var Navigation = React.createClass({
      mixins: [History],
      getPage() {
        if (this.props.location.pathname) {
          let pathname = this.props.location.pathname;
          let pageName = filterPath(pathname);
          return pageName;
        } else {
          return false;
        } 
      },
      decideContent() {
        let page = this.getPage();
        let content;
        switch(page) {
           case 'popular':
              content = 0;
           case 'latest':
              content = 1;
           case 'myideas':
              content = 2;
           default:
              content = 0;
        }
        return content;
      },
      handleTabChange(value) {
        let location = false;
        switch (value) {
           case 0:
             location = 'popular';
             break;
           case 1:
             location = 'latest';
             break;
           case 2:
             location = 'myideas';
             break;
        }
        if (location && location !== this.getPage()) {
          this.history.pushState(null, '/'+location);
        }
      },
      render() {
         var styles = {
          appBar: {
           flexWrap: 'wrap'
          },
          tabs: {
           width: '100%'
          }
         };
         let content = this.decideContent();
         let tabs = <Tabs
                  onChange={this.handleTabChange}
                  value={content}
                >
                  <Tab label="Most Popular Ideas" value={0}  />
                  <Tab label="Latest Ideas" value={1}  />
                  <Tab label="My Ideas" value={2}  />
                </Tabs>;
        return (
         <AppBar showMenuIconButton={false} style={styles.appBar}>
           {tabs}
         </AppBar>
        );
      }
});
```

Comment: This seems alright to me. I'll try to add it to my code.

Answer (score 2):

Check this link, I implemented the solution and worked for me

[Composition in material UI](https://material-ui.com/es/guides/composition/)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me

```
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';

<Link to={menuItem.url} component={RouterLink} aria-current="page">
{menuItem.label}
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to wrap Material-ui Link with Next.js Link

```
import Link from "next/link"
import MuiLink from "@material-ui/core/Link"

const CustomNextLink = ({href, alt}) => ({children, ...rest}) => (
<Link href={href} alt={alt}>
  <MuiLink {...rest}>
    {children}
  </MuiLink>
</Link>)
```

Then pass it to you Tab component

```
<Tab 
 key={...}
 label={title} 
 icon={icon} 
 component={CustomNextLink({href: to, alt: title})}
 style={...}
 className={...}
 classes={{selected: ...}}
 {...a11yProps(index)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `href=""` option as shown below:

```
<Tab
 href="/en/getting-started"
 label="Contact US"
 style={{ color: "white", textDecoration: "none" }}
/>
```

To remove the ripple effect on clicking, use the option `disableRipple`