# Material UI AppBar with React Router 4 Implementation not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I am building a react project with material ui and react router 4 but I can't get a basic example working and I am unsure why!?I don't have any errors and I have everything the basic example on react routers documentation has. I can't seem to find very much help through a standard google search since most people have not moved over to react router 4 yet it seems like. Everything shows up on the page fine but when I click on the tab the route does not actually change.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/IconMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import Tabs from 'material-ui/Tabs/Tabs';
import Tab from 'material-ui/Tabs/Tab';
import Menu from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/menu';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from './Navigation.css';

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
);

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
);

class AppBarComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    logged: true,
  };

  handleChange = (event, logged) => {
    this.setState({ logged });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <AppBar
            title="Title"
            iconElementLeft={
              <IconMenu
                iconButtonElement={<IconButton className={styles.mobileNav}><Menu /></IconButton>}
                iconStyle={{ color: '#fff' }}
              >
                <MenuItem primaryText="Menu Item 1" />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Menu Item 2" />
                <MenuItem primaryText={this.state.logged ? 'Welcome user' : 'Login'} />
              </IconMenu>
          }
          >
            <Tabs className={styles.desktopNav}>
              <Tab label="Menu Item 1" component={Link} to="/" />
              <Tab label="Menu Item 2" component={Link} to="/about" />
              <Tab label={this.state.logged ? 'Welcome user' : 'Login'} />
            </Tabs>
          </AppBar>
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default AppBarComponent;
```

This is my index.js file, its pretty basic nothing special.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import AppBarComponent from './Navigation/Navigation';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <AppBarComponent />
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: Where did you get this syntax from? `<Tab label="Menu Item 1" component={Link} to="/" />` That doesn't look like anything in [their docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs)? You should actually be using the `onActive` prop to manually trigger a redirect. The first example in their docs shows how to navigate to a new route.

Comment: I got it from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843495/material-ui-adding-link-component-from-react-router

Comment: Are you running the same version of Material-UI that they are?

Comment: Nope....  And that was the problem. I have added an answer with what fixed my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the stackoverflow question that I was looking at was using a different version of Material UI. I am on "material-ui": "^0.19.1" which is not able to use

```
<Tab label="Menu Item 1" component={Link} to="/" />
```

For my version I needed to use

```
 <Tab label="Menu Item 1" containerElement={<Link to="/" />}/>
```

I wish this was mentioned somewhere on the documentation...