# Material UI Tab pass props to component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, material-ui

I'm trying to integrate react-router with Material-UI V1 Tabs, as in [this github issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8313), [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843495/material-ui-adding-link-component-from-react-router), and the answer they come to errors out for me.

To my understanding, this is how you are supposed to execute this:

```
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import Link from 'react-router-dom';
/* other code */
<Tab component={Link} to="/" value={'/'} key={'/'} label={'/'}/>
```

However I get the error `[ts] property 'to' does not exist on type...`.

I have also tried:

```
<Tab component={() => <Link to='/' />} value={'/'} key={'/'}] label={'/'}/>
```

But in this case my `Tab` component does not render at all.

Thoughts?

Comment: Try this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/04p1v46qww

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The source of the problem is that `Tab` type is declared this way:

```
declare const Tab: React.ComponentType<TabProps>;
```

`TabProps` of course doesn't have `to` property.

To solve the problem declare a new variable called `LinkTab`:

```
const LinkTab: React.ComponentType<TabProps & LinkProps> = Tab as React.ComponentType<TabProps & LinkProps>;
```

And use it like below:

```
<LinkTab icon={<ListIcon />} component={Link} to="/monitor" />
```

This should compile just fine.

Full code example with imports:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { MonitorContainer } from "Monitor/MonitorContainer";
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch, Link, LinkProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { RemoteContainer } from "Remote/RemoteContainer";
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import { default as Tab, TabProps } from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import ListIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ListAlt';
import RemoteControlIcon from '@material-ui/icons/SettingsRemote';
import './reset.css';
import './index.scss';
import '../assets/fonts/icons/flaticon.css';

const LinkTab: React.ComponentType<TabProps & LinkProps> = Tab as React.ComponentType<TabProps & LinkProps>;

export interface AppState {
    value: number;
}

export class App extends React.Component<{}, AppState> {
    constructor(props: Readonly<{}>) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: 0,
        };
    }

    handleChange = (event: any, value: any) => {
        this.setState({ value });
    };

    render() {
        const { value } = this.state;

        return (
        <div>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Tabs value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} scrollable scrollButtons="off">
                    <LinkTab icon={<ListIcon />} component={Link} to="/monitor" />
                    <LinkTab icon={<RemoteControlIcon />} component={Link} to="/remote" />
                </Tabs>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
        )
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div>
            <App />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/monitor" component={ MonitorContainer } />
                <Route exact path="/remote" component={ RemoteContainer } />
                <Redirect from="/" to="/monitor" />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: did the same with `<MenuItem>` & `<Link>` but unfortunately, it doesn't capture the CSS for menus :( still a groovy trick. `const MenuItemLink: React.ComponentType< MenuItemProps & LinkProps > = MenuItem as React.ComponentType< MenuItemProps & LinkProps >`

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue and in the end my solution was to replace `<Tab>` with `<Link>`:

```
<AppBar>
  <Link to="/links" className={styles.tabButton}>Links</Link>
  <Link to="/docs" className={styles.tabButton}>Docs</Link>
  <Link to="/videos" className={styles.tabButton}>Videos</Link>
</AppBar>
<Switch>
  <Route path="/links" component={MediaLinks} />
  <Route path="/docs" component={MediaDocs} />
  <Route path="/videos" component={MediaVideos} />
</Switch>
```