# Using @Material-UI Tabs as Navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, navbar, material-ui

fairly new to the coding space. I have tried looking everywhere for the answer to this question, and while I've found many answers, none of them work for me.

My problem is that I would like to use @Material-UI tab components as a NavBar, and I can only seem to either 1. turn the tabs into static links that work but have no animation or indicator, or 2. keep the animations but have no functionality as far as changing the page goes.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843495/material-ui-adding-link-component-from-react-router), [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8313), [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/5574), and more, and many of the answers found within each of those.

**Edit**: [Here](https://github.com/bringreaner/reimagined-guacamole) is a Git Repo.

Here is my NavBar component, currently on status #2 where it has animations but not functionality:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Paper, Tabs, Tab } from '@material-ui/core';

const navStyle= {
    backgroundColor: '#220000',
    color: '#fff',
}

export class NavBar extends React.Component {
    state = {
        value: 0,
    };

handleChange = (event, value) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ value });
    console.log(value)
};

render() {      
    return (
        <div>
            <Paper>
                <Tabs
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    indicatorColor={"secondary"}
                    // textColor="secondary"
                    centered
                    style={navStyle}
                >
                    <Tab label="Home" href='/' />
                    <Tab label="About" href='/about' />
                </Tabs>
            </Paper> 
        </div>
    )}
}
```

dependencies:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^1.3.1",
"history": "^4.7.2",
"prop-types": "^15.6.2",
"react": "^16.4.1",
"react-dom": "^16.4.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-scripts": "1.1.4"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make your `Tab` components into React Router `Link` components the same way that it is done in the first example you linked.

Just make sure not to `preventDefault` on the `handleChange` event, since that would stop the links from working.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 0
  };

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Paper>
            <Tabs
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              indicatorColor={"secondary"}
              centered
              style={navStyle}
            >
              <Tab label="Home" to="/" component={Link} />
              <Tab label="About" to="/about" component={Link} />
            </Tabs>
          </Paper>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work in react router v6 because Browser router forces you to use Routes and inside the Routes component you can only have Route components