# How to make a Material UI react Button act as a react-router-dom Link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

How can I make a **Material UI** react `Button` component act as a `Link` component from **react-router-dom** without losing it's original style? Like changing the route on click.

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

<Button variant="contained" color="primary">
    About Page
</Button>
```

To something like this, but maintaining the original `Button` style:

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Button variant="contained" color="primary">
    <Link to="/about">
        About Page
    </Link>
</Button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Material-ui adding Link component from react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843495/material-ui-adding-link-component-from-react-router)

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Okay, this is very easy, I don't know why it was not working with me:

Just do like this:

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Button component={Link} to="/about" variant="contained" color="primary">
  About Page
</Button>
```

You can find more details at https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/routing/.

Comment: how to specify more attribute like `exact` for `Link`?

Comment: This is going beyond the scope of this question, but anyway to make this dynamic? 

Say I do not pass a link prop, don't use `component={ Link }`

Comment: Looks like this is quite a bit different now in MUI 5 release. https://mui.com/guides/routing/

Answer (score 36):

MUI 5 has simplified this even further. Simply provide a MUI `Button` with a `href` attribute as follows:

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';


<Button href="/" variant="contained">
  Link
</Button>
```

Comment: This should be a selected answer. Thanks.

Comment: This don't use react-router Link component. It use 'a' html component that is the default one.

Comment: @Maiky The default component used for the `Button` when supplying an `href` property is an anchor `<a>`. However, you can specify what component to use with the property `LinkComponent`, for example `LinkComponent={Link}` .

Answer (score 15):

You need to wrap the `<Button />` inside the `<Link />` component.

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const ButtonWithLink = () => (
  <Link to="/about">
   <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
     About Page
   </Button>
  </Link>
)
```

Comment: this way also works. just need to give styling to remove underline from `Link`. Thanks

Comment: This was extremely helpful for a problem I was having where I have a wrapper for `Link` and so the `component={Link}` method resulted in lost styling from Material-UI for some reason. This method restored the styling.

Comment: A Button inside of a Link is not valid HTML (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5) and even if parsable by browsers, its poor semantics and causes a11y problems.

Answer (score 0):

This way worked for me

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const YourComponentName = () =>{

    const history = useHistory();
    const handleRoutes = (path) =>{
       history.push(path)
    }
    
  return(
    <>
      ...
      <Button 
         variant="contained" 
         color="primary" 
         onClick={() => handleRoutes('/about')}>
         About Page
      </Button>
      ...
    </>
)
}
```

Comment: It will not behave the same as link, e.g.: you cannot click mouse wheel to open link in another tab. I would not recommend this approach as it may result in poor UX.