# react-router-dom with material-ui

Tags: material-ui, react-router-dom

Im using material-ui and react-router-dom in my react (typescript) application

I have tried to use the following tip/help, so that when a user clicks a button (or whatever) he gets redirected to that route. Very basic stuff. When I click on the button, the url is updated in the url-window in my browser, but the correct component is not loaded. I had this working using bootstrap (and 'react-router-bootstrap's NavigationLink), but now Im stuck. Any tips how to get this working

(Im also using Mobx as state handler), Im also happy with any other router, if that makes my life simpler

https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/
and
[How to make a Material UI react Button act as a react-router-dom Link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642532/how-to-make-a-material-ui-react-button-act-as-a-react-router-dom-link)

Note that if I hit enter in the url-window I get routed correctly (to right component)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this method to achieve a correct react-router-dom link for a `Button` component from material-ui.

Define a `LinkComponent`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export const LinkComponent = (props: any) => {
  return <Link {...props} />;
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<Button
  variant={'outlined'}
  color={'primary'}
  component={LinkComponent}
  to={'/'}>
  HomePage
</Button>
```

If you don't want to create a dedicated component for this purpose, you can use it as a lambda function as a component prop for the `<Button>`.

Comment: Hi Ammar! Thanks for your reply. I get 2 errors here, meybe Im misunderstand you. I created the LinkComponent, but I get the error "(TS) could not find name href", so I removed the "href ||"-part. On the <Button-part I get that to does not exist (also a TS-error)

Comment: ...but I cant find a to-attribute here either https://material-ui.com/api/button/

Comment: ... and even if I hardcode <Link to='/hardcodedurl' its still the same. The url i updated but my components arent loaded...

Comment: @Cowborg Sorry for the href not found error, I updated the answer, please try it now.

Comment: tried that too, no difference. I think my problem is how I wire up the routing with mobx. I used react-router-bootstrap before, but since Im not using bootstrap now I need to look over that again ... I think