# Using a Link as a Material UI Grid item's component prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

According to [the Material UI documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/), you can supply either a string or a component to the `component` property of a `Grid` item.

I would like to change an existing `Grid` instance to act as an anchor, but I want to accomplish this using a `Link` component instead of supplying `'a'` as the `component` property (this is because using `'a'` as the component property forces a full refresh, where I assume using a `Link` component does not.)

The problem is that it's not actually documented anywhere how to accomplish using a component with this property instead of a string. I can get it to render as an anchor using the string overload, but not with a component.

I have tried several methods of supplying a component to this property, but the simplest case is something like this:

```
<Grid component={ Link }>
```

But it is always highlighted as an error, with "No overload method matches this call" as the error message.

The overload for the `component` property is as follows:

```
component?: string | React.ComponentType<Omit<GridProps, StrippedProps>>;
```

So my question is, how is this actually meant to be accomplished? It doesn't seem to be as simple as supplying a component type as the documentation suggests, or [like you can do with a `Button` component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51642640).

Edit: here is an example of code that is giving me this error.

```
const Test: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  return(
    <Grid component={ Link }/>
  )
}
```

I forgot to mention that I'm using TypeScript in a mature react/redux codebase. I think this is a TypeScript-specific error, as I'm not seeing it in codesandbox.io. It's not a versioning issue as I've been doing all tests in the same version of Material UI Core (4.1.1).

Error message is as follows:

```
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: GridProps, context?: any): ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | Component<...> | null', gave the following error.
    Type 'typeof Link' is not assignable to type 'string | ComponentClass<Pick<GridProps, "color" | "style" | "title" | "children" | "ref" | "defaultChecked" | "defaultValue" | "suppressContentEditableWarning" | "suppressHydrationWarning" | ... 244 more ... | "zeroMinWidth">, any> | FunctionComponent<...> | undefined'.
      Type 'typeof Link' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<Pick<GridProps, "color" | "style" | "title" | "children" | "ref" | "defaultChecked" | "defaultValue" | "suppressContentEditableWarning" | "suppressHydrationWarning" | ... 244 more ... | "zeroMinWidth">, any>'.
        Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
          Property 'to' is missing in type 'Pick<GridProps, "color" | "style" | "title" | "children" | "ref" | "defaultChecked" | "defaultValue" | "suppressContentEditableWarning" | "suppressHydrationWarning" | ... 244 more ... | "zeroMinWidth">' but required in type 'Readonly<LinkProps>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: PropsWithChildren<GridProps>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | Component<...> | null', gave the following error.
    Type 'typeof Link' is not assignable to type 'string | ComponentClass<Pick<GridProps, "color" | "style" | "title" | "children" | "ref" | "defaultChecked" | "defaultValue" | "suppressContentEditableWarning" | "suppressHydrationWarning" | ... 244 more ... | "zeroMinWidth">, any> | FunctionComponent<...> | undefined'.
      Type 'typeof Link' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<Pick<GridProps, "color" | "style" | "title" | "children" | "ref" | "defaultChecked" | "defaultValue" | "suppressContentEditableWarning" | "suppressHydrationWarning" | ... 244 more ... | "zeroMinWidth">, any>'.
```

Comment: Could please attach minimum code to reproduce the issue? Because it's worked for me.

Comment: @Alex added a code example and some more detail

Comment: can you try passing the `component` as `<Grid component={<Link/>}/>`

Comment: Before `const Test......`, import section, please

Comment: The import section is very long as there are other things happening in this tsx file, but Link and Grid are both being imported from @material-ui/core. For the sake of simplicity this export is defined outside of any other component.

Comment: @sumanthmadishetty Thank you for the suggestion, but it gave the same error message (basically) as the one I just added to my OP. Difference being it's now stating type 'Element' is not assignable.

Comment: Hmm, the error seems to go away if I define it as { Link as any } instead of just { Link }. I guess it's something like a strictness issue. Further problem is I can't assign a href attribute to the element either, whereas in a normal basic react sandbox this is perfectly fine to do.