# Material UI <Tab /> component loses styling when wrapped with React Router <Link />

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My `<Tab />` component works fine before being wrapped in a React Router Dom `<Link />`. I believe `<Link />` wraps an `<a>` tag around its child causing a styling override.

The other possibility is that `<Tab />` must be exactly one level below `<Tabs />` for the styling to pass correctly.

How to fix this? I'm open to using other libraries to get Material UI's styling to override.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

export default () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs value={adminView} centered>
          <Link to='/add-coupon'> // adding this turns the styling into "classic blue underline"
            <Tab
              label="Add New Coupon"
              value={addNewCoupon}
              onClick={() => setAdminView(addNewCoupon)}
            />
          </Link>
        </Tabs>
    </AppBar>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Material-ui adding Link component from react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843495/material-ui-adding-link-component-from-react-router)

Comment: How are you styling? I don’t see any in this code

Comment: Besides Material UI I also use Styled Components though not in this module