# How the `component` property works with Tab component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I was trying to change URL path by clicking the `<Tab/>` component, I searched it through the [Material-UI Tab API](https://material-ui.com/api/tab/) but couldn't find anything. Then I came across with the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51524353/11022754) as

```js
 <Tab label='Most popular ideas'  to='/myPath' component={Link} />
```

The question is how can you use `component` property even if it's not one of the `<Tab/>`'s props and how it's working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation:

> Any other properties supplied will be provided to the root element
>   (ButtonBase).

Here's the API props for ButtonBase:
https://v4-0-2.material-ui.com/api/button-base/

Props you'll provide to the `Tab` element which not being used by the element will bubble down to the next component, which is in this case `ButtonBase` that uses your `component` prop.